# Compare rows in two different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets to compare. Sometimes a whole row of data may be added, deleted or changed. I need to compare this to the other worksheet.

For example, if one worksheet looks like:

```
(Sheet 1)
Max J 89231 
Sam L 82313
Penny H 23456
Mary K 91423
```

And the next Sheet looks like:

```
(Sheet 2)
Sam L 82313    (Max J Removed)
John S 71234   (Penny H changed to John S)
Mary K 91423
Thomas N 18123 (Thomas N added)
```

How do I display the differences in rows for the two sheets, in e.g. sheet3 using a macro?

```
(Sheet 3)
Max J 89231 
John S 71234  
Thomas N 18123
```

Comment: What is the layout of the sheets? In particular -- is it enough to look in the first column to see if a given row has been added or deleted? Also --  is the relative order of rows that are common to both sheets the same in both sheets, or can rows be permuted in addition to being added or deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Have two loops in each sheet - that check Sheet1 against Sheet2, and insert differences in Sheet3, and then Sheet 2 against Sheet1, and insert differences in Sheet3 also.

In half pseudo half vba code , something like this for Sheet1:

```
for i = beginning row in Sheet 1 to last Row in Sheet1
   'matchFound variable concludes if match is found. Initially no match
   matchFound=false
   continue=true ' boolean to tell us whether its worth proceeding if we have identified a match
   if (continue) then
       for j = beginning row in Sheet 2 to last Row in Sheet2
            'if Sheet1 row has been matched in a row in Sheet2 
            if Sheet1.Cells(i,1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(j,1).Value and
                 Sheet1.Cells(i,2).Value = Sheet2.Cells(j,2).Value then
                  matchFound = true
                  continue=false
            endif
        next j
    endif

    'no match found
    if matchFound = false then
           sheet3.Range(last used row + 1, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i,1).Value
           sheet3.Range(last used row + 1, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i,2).Value

    endif

next i
```

Use the above logic also for sheet2 but which checks those in sheet2 and not in Sheet1, and adds to Sheet3 - so sheet 2 is the outer for loop this time.